# WOULD meaning in those sentences

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage, modal-verbs, future-tense

1.I think we **would** be better off friends.

2.I think that i **would** die.

3.I **would** die for you.

4.I think i **would** just cut the wire.

Why **would** is used in those sentences?

I think it is not conditional.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/would

> 1 PAST INTENTIONS/EXPECTATIONS used to say what someone intended to do
>   or expected to happen
>
> They said they **would** meet us at 10.30 at the
>   station.
>
> She said she **wouldn’t** be coming to the library anymore.
>
> Arnold knew he **would** be tired the next day.
>
> It **would** soon be dark.

Comment: Can you explain it more specifically for each sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Sometime "would" gives future meanings in imaginary situations.

In your example 3, the if part is silence. I would die for you (if you......)

meaning is, I will die for you (in imaginary world, not in real world but in real world it will be, I will not die for you)

Comment: I think in real world, he will still die for he/she.